# PHP exec, output errors only

Tags: php

I am using PHP exec to run a Powershell script to create a new user that is being submitted via a HTML form.  What I am looking to do is output only errors from this command on the webpage so any IT team member can see if anything went wrong.  Here is what I have:

```
$psPath = 'c:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe -version 5';
$psDIR = "d:\\wamp64\\www\\includes\\";
$psScript = "NewHire.ps1";
$runCMD = $psPath. ' -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned '.$psDIR.$psScript

$createuser = exec($runCMD.' 2>&1', $out);
```

When I do a `var_dump($out)`, it shows both the output and errors.  I tried changing it to `exec($runCMD.' &1', $out)` but it shows output only.  If I try `exec($runCMD.' 2>', $out)`, it doesn't run my command.  Is there a way I can display errors only in the $out varible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this works for stderr only:

```
exec($runCMD.' >&2' , $out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
exec($runCMD."2>&1 1>/dev/null ",$out);
```

Comment: @codedByMi I have executed my code and it is working fine. Then only I posted.

Comment: I tried your example, but my command didn't run.  I should have mentioned that this is a WAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this might help

```
public static function exec_alt($cmd)
{
    exec($cmd, $output);
    if (!$output) {
        /**
         * FIXME: for some reason exec() returns empty output array @mine,'s machine.
         *        Somehow proc_open() approach (below) works, but doesn't work at
         *        test machines - same empty output with both pipes and temporary
         *        files (not we bypass shell wrapper). So use it as a fallback.
         */
        $output = array();
        $handle = proc_open($cmd, array(1 => array('pipe', 'w')), $pipes, null, null, array('bypass_shell' => true));
        if (is_resource($handle)) {
            $output = explode("\n", stream_get_contents($pipes[1]));
            fclose($pipes[1]);
            proc_close($handle);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

if you on windows 7, you might need to:

> Disabling User Account Control (UAC)

run

> UserAccountControlSettings.exe

at 
`C:\Windows\System32\UserAccountControlSettings.exe` 
and select "Never notify"